# Error with my Activity, FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I've got a problem when trying to run my app in Android Studio. I get a

`FATAL EXCEPTION: main`

more precisely there seems to be a problem at:

`dancam.com.chords.ChordsListActivity.onCreate(ChordsListActivity.java:13)`

which is:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_chords_list);
```

here is the ChordsListActivity class:

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class ChordsListActivity extends ListActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chords_list);

    String[] accordi = new String[] {"Do maggiore", "Re maggiore", "Si maggiore"};
    String[] note = new String[] {"note: Do, Mi, Sol", "note: La, Re, Fa#", "note: Fa#, Si, Re#"};
    int[] immagini = new int[] {R.drawable.do_maggiore, R.drawable.re_maggiore, R.drawable.si_maggiore};

    CustomListAdapter adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), accordi, note, immagini);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

I was kinda able to solve it by extending `Activity` instead of `ListActivity` but then I cannot use the `setListAdapter()` method.

I'd really appreciate if someone could help me fix the code!

please let me know if you need me to post the custom Adapter or any other file.

**Edit:** added the whole stack trace

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: dancam.com.chords, PID: 3080
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{dancam.com.chords/dancam.com.chords.ChordsListActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:243)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:398)
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166)
at dancam.com.chords.ChordsListActivity.onCreate(ChordsListActivity.java:13)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: You should provide the entire stacktrace so we can figure out *why* the fatal exception is occurring

Comment: @Arpan I have added it as code I don't know if it's right. Anyway thank you for helping me out

Comment: @MikeM Since I have a custom `listView` I should extend `Activity`. But why then doesn't `setListAdapter` work?

Comment: If you want to extend just `Activity`, then you call `setAdapter()` - not `setListAdapter()` - on the `ListView` variable itself, after you've initialized it with `findViewById()`. A regular `Activity` doesn't have the `setListAdapter()` method. That's just a convenience method in `ListActivity` that calls `setAdapter()` on the `ListView` for you.

Comment: Why do you want to use a ListView? That's a bit old approach. Use a RecyclerView instead.

Comment: @Todor because I'm new to Android and I have never heard of recyclerView before. I'll have a look at the documentation too

Comment: This question has a bad title, see your stacktrace "Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'", which is the dupe (so if you searched on that error you would have found the problem, as dupe I can't really see how to improve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is problem with `ListView`.
Go to `R.layout.activity_chords_list` and add `<ListView>` and set id `android:id="@android:id/list"`

Like Exception says: 'Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

It should works if rest of the code is ok.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, does it work even if I have a custom row layout?

Comment: Yes, you need to create your own LayoutManager. There is few by default Linear  (as listview ), grid.

Comment: No, if there is like img, couple of textview-s and etc. You should use your custom ListAdapter. If it is like one TextView you can avoid it.

Comment: I have a custom layout that's why I was asking

Comment: Ah sorry i didn't see, you have CustomAdapter and all these staff. No you don't need to use id android:id/list, use just @+id/list instead.

Answer (score 0):

When you extend from ListActivity, it already has ListView, but Activity doesn't. You have to create list inbActivity's layout- better use RecyclerView instead of List view. In your activity create RecyclerView reference, initialize it in onCreate. Create adapter for your data in activity (onCreate method). Finnaly, set adapter to listview reference. In order to modify data in a list, set new data in adapter and call .notifyDatasetChange () on it. Notice, for RecyclerView you will also need LayoutManager (see docs)

Comment: thank you for your answer but what is RecyclerView and how do I use it?

Comment: It newer version of ListView, which scroll faster and allows to arrange items in any ways (two columns, for example) see one of tutorials, https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/android-l-recyclerview-and-cardview-tutorial/156

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: As stated in answer above, you can fix problem by changing id of your list- ListActivity expect standard id

Comment: I ment answer below

Comment: I actually can't because I'm using a custom row layout